# Iteration of objects on a Form

Tags: c++, loops, c++builder

I am new to Embarcadero C++Builder. My question is: is it possible to iterate the Properties of more than one object with a loop?

Example: if I have many labels, how is it possible to do some similar to this:

```
 for(int i=1; i<4; i++){
    Label[i]->Caption = "xxxxx";
 }
```

instead of writing this:

```
Labe1->Caption  = "xxxxx"; 
Labe2->Caption  = "xxxxx"; 
Labe3->Caption  = "xxxxx";
```

Comment: Sure, you can have an array of objects instead of separately named objects.

Comment: btw your loop skips the first caption

Comment: If you're talking about a VCL forms app, then each form has a built-in Controls[] array.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yes, but it is not really sorted in any meaningful way, and if there are more than just labels on the Form, you would have to manually check every object for what you are looking for. There are better ways to handle that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your own array for this.

In the Form's header, define the array:

```
private:
    TLabel* labels[4];
```

Then populate the array in the Form's constructor:

```
labels[0] = Label1;
labels[1] = Label2;
labels[2] = Label3;
labels[3] = Label4;
```

Or:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    labels[i] = static_cast<TLabel*>(FindComponent("Label"+IntToStr(i+1)));
}
```

Then you can loop through the array when needed:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    labels[i]->Caption = "xxxxx";
}
```

Comment: This was what I needed. Simple and elegant. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

If you've used the IDE to create the TLabels, you need to manually create a container storing pointers to them.

In your forms header file:

```
#include <vector>
```

And add this to the protected part of your form:

```
std::vector<TLabel*> myLabels;
```

And add this to the constructor:

```
myLabels.push_back(Label1);
myLabels.push_back(Label2);
myLabels.push_back(Label3);
```

Or perhaps even this:

```
for(int c=0; c<ComponentCount; ++c) {
    TLabel* tmp = dynamic_cast<TLabel*>(Components[c]);
    if(tmp) myLabels.push_back(tmp);
}
```

You can now iterate over your labels using the C++11 range based for loop:

```
for(auto l : myLabels) {
    l->Caption = "xxxxx";
}
```

Comment: Not the classic one but the clang based one does. I never use the classic one in new projects for that reason.

Comment: I use Embarcadero C++ Builder, this code doesn't compile. Thanks anyway. The solution proposed by Remy Lebeau is the right solution for me.

Comment: Which version of C++ Builder are you using? Are you using the classic compiler or the clang based one?

Comment: Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.1 Berlin

Comment: Ok, then it will compile if you turn off using the classic compiler.

Comment: See [How to use the Clang-based compiler for Windows 32-bit projects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Win32_Clang-enhanced_Compilers#How_to_use_the_Clang-based_compiler_for_Windows_32-bit_projects) in Embarcadero's documentation.